# Replace specific value in column in R

Tags: r, replace

I have a variable in a data frame which consists of either 5 or 6 digits/characters. Those values in the variable with 5 digits are all numbers e.g. 27701 those with 6 digits however all have a character 'C' preceding the numbers e.g. C22701.

How can I replace the 'C' characters with 999 for example?

I have tried:

```
replace(data$varname,'C',999)
```

Any ideas folks?

Comment: `data$varname <- gsub('C', '999', data$varname)` maybe? If `varname` is a `factor`, it could cause problems though

Comment: What format do you want the variable in the end?  `Character`?  `Factor`?  `Numeric`?

Answer (score 2):

`data$varname <- as.numeric(gsub('C', '999', data$varname))` should do the trick, I think.  Assuming you want a numeric vector in the end.  If you want a character vector, then you can leave `as.numeric` off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `substring` to remove the first letter, and `paste0` to add 999 to it.

```
> x <- c("C000", "P1745")
> paste0("999", substring(x,2))
# [1] "999000"  "9991745"
```